Overiding Only a Few Specific Canonical Links with Default Value = Yes - Magento 2
In Magento 2, we have Stores -> Catalog -> SEO -> "Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories" and "Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products" set to "Yes". This works well except for one specific instance.
We use two different "Shop By" categories in the header menu for UX purposes.
Example:
Shop by Category -> Aquariums -> Saltwater Fish
Shop by Fish -> Saltwater Fish -> Aquariums
Unfortunately I wasn't around in development to avoid duplicate pages. So I want to change the Canonical link for the "Shop by Fish" pages to point towards the "Shop by Category" equivalents to avoid duplicate content.
If I change the link in the XML file and save everything, will the default canonical links override my changes?
If I change the value in "Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories" from Yes to No will all the values reset and delete the canonical links?
